# I am incrementing, but still get "An APK with this package name and version code already exists."

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, oculus, gear-vr

first post for me. I posted this to Oculus forums also.

I am trying to update my Alpha build with a second APK but am receiving the following error:

> An APK with this package name and version code already exists. Please
>   increment the version code and then resubmit your update.

My previously uploaded Alpha has a version of 1.0 and version code 1.

My new Android Manifest has the following:

```
android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="2.0"
```

so I have incremented both the version name and the version code but still get the error. Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: versionName is not really useful here and shouldn't be the problem. Where do you chnage your versionCode? What directory is the Manifest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that you also have to set the version number and code in Unity under Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Other. I was just setting the version number in the Manifest XML itself and hadn't heard of this setting in Unity.